# React Native metro bundler not starting automatically only for android

Tags: android, react-native

`react-native start` doesn't start a metro bundler. I need manually run `yarn start`. What can be a reason of such problem ?

Comment: It happened after migration from react-native v. 0.59.10 to 0.63

Comment: Show me your package.json.

Comment: @hongdevelop https://uploadfiles.io/doibjel2

Comment: Could you try `react-native run-android` ?

Answer (score 2):

There's possibility that the 8081 port is in use - how about

react-native start --port=8080

Comment: If port is in use the error message will be shown in terminal. But in my case it looks like:       `Server is running`, but the separate terminal with bundler doesn't appear. I have to type `yarn start`. In ios version it is implemented by calling a phase "Start packager" for  .